# href links to open network shared files are not working with tomcat V-9.0.27 in linux

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a simple JSP page that retrieves network location and users will access the network files, using href file link that work in local tomcat but the same link does not work from a Linux server's tomcat.

below code works in local windows tomcat to open a shared server file.

```
<A href="\\\\server\folder1\folder2\Master20-%20Ref.dwg" target=_blank>Master -Ref.dwg</A>
```

when this is deployed in the Linux server's tomcat the links do not work, my tomcat version is 9.0.27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `href` attribute should be an absolute URL or an URI path relative to the current page.

In your case you need to use absolute URLs. There is an almost standard URI scheme `smb` (cf. its [Internet Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crhertel-smb-url-12)) that works on Linux clients, but not on Windows clients.

For Windows clients you should probably use a non-standard application of the `file` scheme (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#How_many_slashes?)), which works on Windows clients. You should format your links in one of two formats:

```xml
<a href="file://server/share/folder1/folder2/Master20-%20Ref.dwg">Master -Ref.dwg</a>
```

or

```xml
<a href="file:////server/share/folder1/folder2/Master20-%20Ref.dwg">Master -Ref.dwg</a>
```

**Edit:** Following OP's comment, this should work the best:

```xml
<a href="file:////server\share\folder1\folder2\Master20-%20Ref.dwg">Master -Ref.dwg</a>
```

Comment: Great, the second method is working, but when with the actual location it is not working.. :(, tied all possibilities...

Comment: Did you replace the `\ ` to `/`? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah did check thoroughly, the above link works work sometimes and some it does not.

Comment: for me this is working <a href="file:////server\share\folder1\folder2\Master20-%20Ref.dwg">Master -Ref.dwg</a> . please add this link as well, thanks by the way should help other too...