# Href to open netwrok file works from locahost, does not work from the linux tomcat server

Tags: html, linux, browser, hyperlink, href

I have the JSP page uploaded to the tomcat server, this page is used to open files from the network drives connected to our systems in windows(works only in IE).

The href link below works like a charm in IE:

1. To open an folder :

```
<a href='\\\\INBLRGVE4XJDN53\\Users\\Documents\\POC-NW\\folder1'>fodler1</a>
```

2. To open a file in browser tab:

```
<a href='\\\\INBLRGVE4XJDN53\\Users\\Documents\\POC-NW\\folder1\\textfile1.txt'>textfile1</a>
```

but the above same code when deployed in a Linux tomcat server does not work.

Should there be any configurations done on the server-side, Request to help me on this.

here there is another post which states how to open a network link from IE, but this works from localhost:
[href links to open network shared files are not working with tomcat V-9.0.27 in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350755/href-links-to-open-network-shared-files-are-not-working-with-tomcat-v-9-0-27-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [href links to open network shared files are not working with tomcat V-9.0.27 in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350755/href-links-to-open-network-shared-files-are-not-working-with-tomcat-v-9-0-27-in)

Comment: You have suggested a good post, but that works only in localhost, not in a server of Linux tomcat.

Comment: You posted your question twice: if this is a new problem, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66453079/edit) your question, provide a link to your previous question and explain how this constitutes a new problem.

Comment: Remark: your problem does not depend on how you **generate** your page (Tomcat, JSP, …), but only how your browser **interprets** the page (which browser you are using). It might depend on the URL on the page (whether it is `http://localhost` or `http://example.com`), so you should provide all these information in your question.